# Attachtment required to create a task

Tags: attachment, tasks

is possible to force to the users to attacht a document in order to create a new task? We want to use the tasks object to manage sales members resquests but we need to set as required to attacht a document in order to create a new task. I have already tried with Task Validation Rules but it has not visibility over the attachtments related list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, the task has to be inserted (have Id assigned) before you could reuse that Id while adding an attachment - same logic applies whether it's from UI or Apex code for example. Not sure how do you imagine doing that...

What you could do is to write a trigger that would prevent updates of tasks of certain type if they have no attachments. Or maybe block insertion of closed tasks without attachment (you'd have to make it somehow type-specific because that way you'll nuke the creation of completed activities when an email is sent out for example).

---

I've modified the code from your comment a bit, try it out:

```
trigger DocumentAttached on Task (before update) {
    // "after insert" won't work for sure. 
    // It's pretty much guaranteed to have 0 attachments there 
    // (well, unless you have other triggers but let's not go down that rabbit hole)
    // also - in "after" triggers you can't modify the original record directly, 
    // "before" is better for what you're trying to do

    for(Task t : [SELECT Id,
        (SELECT Id FROM Attachments LIMIT 1)
        FROM Task
        WHERE Id IN : trigger.new]){

        trigger.newMap(t.Id).Questionnaire_attached__c = !t.Attachments.isEmpty();
        // looks like black magic but should work ;)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, do you think it will work if I create and intermediate Status between Open and Completed (Submitted for example) and require to attacht a document in order to move from Open to Completed? Will I need to do that with trigger? thanks

Comment: You'll need a trigger on Attachment to increment/decrement some kind of "count of attachments" flag on Task because you can't make a rollup summary between Task & Attachment. Then it'd be a simple val. rule for example. Or make a trigger on task that'd contain the check.

Comment: I have create the following trigger on Task in order to set as True a field (Questionnaire_attached) if there is an attachment. But It does not work. This message is showed: "Record is read-only" but this field is not read-only. Coudl somebody help me with this? trigger DocumentAttached on Task (after insert , after update) {
    for(Task tsk : Trigger.new){
        Attachment[] attList = [select id, name, body from Attachment where ParentId = :Trigger.new[0].id];
            if(attList.size() > 0)
           {
            tsk.Questionnaire_attached__c=true;
           }
    } 
}

Answer (score 0):

Attachtment is assigned to object based on object Id.
So there is no possibility to achieve your requiments by validation rule.
In my oppinion best way will be custom VF page for creating new Tasks